# Cannot import Vue: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

```
npm install vue --save
```

Stuff gets installed and stored in `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, including:

```
"vue": "^2.5.21",   
"vue-router": "^3.0.2",
"vue-server-renderer": "^2.5.21",
```

But when I run

```
node src/main.js
```

with sourcecode (this is the full main.js file, 1 line)

```
import Vue from 'vue';
```

I get the error

```
src/main.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Vue from 'vue'
                                                                     ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The import line is used in many Hello worlds, something simple must be wrong.
Node version is v10.15.0.
For example https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: Show your whole `main.js` file.

Comment: @Styx My whole main.js is there, it only consists of the import statement, the error is in line 1.

Comment: And `node` version?

Comment: This is the most confusing and most difficult Hello World I have ever done. It was easier with C/C++

Comment: Ah, sorry, I got confused as well. You should use `const Vue = require('vue');` instead.

Comment: @Styx nice, easy, works can you put it as answer and maybe expain why it's suggested to use `import` when it doesn't even work?

Comment: Vue code needs to run in the browser, not with node. Node is used to build Vue projects with webpack as a precompilcation step which bundles all modules together into code suitable for loading in the web browser (this is what vue-cli does). See [Installation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html) for more information.

Comment: @DecadeMoon Thanks for providing additional information. I am trying to use `vue-server-renderer` effectively but going from one Hello World to the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS supports CommonJS (`require`/`module.exports`) modules only, not ES6 (`import`/`export`) you were trying to use.

Those examples you're referring to probable mention using babel transpiler. Under the hood it converts using ES6 modules to CommonJS ones, so node could work.

For example, you can create your test project like this:

```
npm -g i vue-cli
vue init webpack-simple vue-test-project
cd vue-test-project
npm i
npm run dev
```

This will install Babel transpiler, Webpack bundler and other needed packages. After that you can use ES6 modules as long as you run `npm run dev` (to run) or `npm run build` (to build).

Useful link to read: [Vue.js → Installation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html)

---

*This is an answer on "Why `import` doesn't work?" question. As [@DecadeMoon has pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54144760/cannot-import-vue-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier#comment95121855_54144760), `vue` is not supposed to be run in `node`.*